# Will the default constructor call MPI_Comm_free?

Tags: c++, class, mpi, destructor

Lets say we have the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mpi.h>

class MyClass {
   public:

      MyClass(std::vector<double>& v0,
              std::vector<double>& v1,
              std::vector<double>& v2,
              MPI_Comm mycomm);
      ~MyClass() = default;

   private:

      std::vector<double> v0_,v1_,v2_;
      MPI_Comm mycomm_;
};

MyClass::MyClass(std::vector<double>& v0,std::vector<double>& v1,std::vector<double>& v2, MPI_Comm mycomm) : v0_(v0), v1_(v1), v2_(v2){

  // Get the group of processes in MPI_COMM_WORLD
  MPI_Group world_group;
  MPI_Comm_group(mycomm, &world_group);

  const int ranks[2] = {0,1};

  // Construct a group containing all of the ranks in world_group
  MPI_Group new_group;
  MPI_Group_incl(world_group, 2, ranks, &new_group);

  // Create a new communicator based on the group
  MPI_Comm_create_group(mycomm, new_group, 0, &mycomm_);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int IdProc,NbProc;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

  std::vector<double> v0 = {1,2};
  std::vector<double> v1 = {1,2,3};
  std::vector<double> v2 = {1,2,3,4};

  {
      MyClass my_class(v0,v1,v2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
 
  MPI_Finalize();
  
  return 0;
}
```

Will the default constructor actually call `MPI_Comm_free(&MyComm);` ?

If not, when I call MPI_Comm_free in my own implementation of the destructor of MyClass, do I need to call destructors for all members of MyClass or will it call default constructor for MyStruct and the std::vectors ?

I've tried keeping `~MyClass() = default;` and still add the call for `MPI_Comm_free(&MyComm);` in the implementation of the destructor, and it of course through back "you can't do that, you explicitly said the destructor was default".

I was expecting that it would check if there are default constructor for some members and if so call them, and then execute the code in my own destructor. But I see now why it can't do such a thing, if for example my implementation would need to do something with v1 before deallocate it, it wouldn't work.

Comment: You explicitly coded your default constructor to *not* do anything at all. So no, it won't call `MPI_Comm_free` (or anything else).

Comment: And `~MyClass(){} = default;`? Does that even build? Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. Unrelated problems and errors tend to distract from the actual problem you might have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry went to fast with the `{}`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've edit stuff, if you have an MPI implementation running, this minimal code, should work

Comment: If you expect the *destructor* to somehow call a function, then no that won't happen. The program will do exactly what you tell it to do, and if you have a defaulted destructor then it won't do anything. If you want `MPI_Comm_free` to be called in `MyClass` destruction, then you need to explicitly call it.

Comment: And if you have a non-defaulted destructor, you should probably take some time to think about [the rules of three, five and zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). I would suggest you wrap the `MPI_Comm` object in another class that does the `MPI_Comm_Free` automatically on destruction, and therefore use the rule of zero (and don't define, or even declare the destructor). You can use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for this actually, using `MPI_Comm_Free` as the destruct funciton.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so after exiting the scope in which I create an instance of MyClass, you're saying that the default destructor does not do anything and does not even free v0,v1 and v2 ?

Comment: All the member objects of the `MyClass` object will be destructed. As part of that destruction the `std::vector<double>` destructor will run. ***But*** `MPI_Comm` isn't a C++ object with a destructor. The life-time of the member variable will end, and the variable will cease to exist, but there's no automatic code cleanup.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok so indeed I should make the destructor a non-default one, call MPI_Comm_free(&mycomm_). But then what happens to v0, v1 and v2 ? Will they be freed if I don't specify anything ?

Comment: The vector destructors will run as normal, even if you have a destructor with other code in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mpi.h>

class MyClass {
   public:

      MyClass(std::vector<double>& v0,
              std::vector<double>& v1,
              std::vector<double>& v2,
              MPI_Comm mycomm);
      ~MyClass();

   private:

      std::vector<double> v0_,v1_,v2_;
      MPI_Comm mycomm_;
};

MyClass::~MyClass(){
  MPI_Comm_free(&mycomm_);
}

MyClass::MyClass(std::vector<double>& v0,std::vector<double>& v1,std::vector<double>& v2, MPI_Comm mycomm) : v0_(v0), v1_(v1), v2_(v2){

  // Get the group of processes in MPI_COMM_WORLD
  MPI_Group world_group;
  MPI_Comm_group(mycomm, &world_group);

  const int ranks[2] = {0,1};

  // Construct a group containing all of the ranks in world_group
  MPI_Group new_group;
  MPI_Group_incl(world_group, 2, ranks, &new_group);

  // Create a new communicator based on the group
  MPI_Comm_create_group(mycomm, new_group, 0, &mycomm_);
}

// MPI_Comm build_a_new_comm_out_of_mpicommworld(MPI_Comm& mycomm){

//   MPI_Comm newcomm;
//   // Get the group of processes in MPI_COMM_WORLD
//   MPI_Group world_group;
//   MPI_Comm_group(mycomm, &world_group);

//   const int ranks[2] = {0,1};

//   // Construct a group containing all of the ranks in world_group
//   MPI_Group new_group;
//   MPI_Group_incl(world_group, 2, ranks, &new_group);

//   // Create a new communicator based on the group
//   MPI_Comm_create_group(mycomm, new_group, 0, &newcomm);
//   return newcomm;
// }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int IdProc,NbProc;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

  std::vector<double> v0 = {1,2};
  std::vector<double> v1 = {1,2,3};
  std::vector<double> v2 = {1,2,3,4};

  {
      MyClass my_class(v0,v1,v2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
 
  MPI_Finalize();
  
  return 0;
}
```

Deleting the "default" parameter of the constructor and call for `MPI_Comm_free(&mycomm_)` in the destructor.

And to answer the initial questions:

1. The default constructor **does not** call `MPI_Comm_free` to deallocate memory of a communicator.
2. There is no need for further instructions, the `std::vector<double>` will be deallocate by the destructor.

Answer (score -1):

Communicator handling and constructors is a tricky subject. When do you `MPI_Comm_dup` in a copy constructor? Please take a look at https://github.com/rabauke/mpl which is a well-designed idiomatic C++ wrapper around MPI. It addresses that sort of issue. No need to write your own C++ wrappers.